# $\frac{dx}{dt} = \sin(x) +\tan(x) + x^2.$ How do I get $x$ as a function of $t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

How to solve equations like this one?

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \sin(x) +\tan(x) + x^2$

I have tried a few substitutions but none of them seems to work because of the $x^2$ term.

Comment: for near point: $x(t)=0$, we have $\sin (x(t))\approx x(t)$ and $\tan (x(t))\approx x(t)$ then:$x'(t)=x(t)^2+2 x(t)$

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it has a closed solution.
If you want a numerical solution, you can rearrange it as 
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sin x+\tan x+x^2} = t + C$$
and feed the integral into your calculator.
There are some constant solutions, where $\sin x + \tan x+x^2=0$.  They are just above $(n+1/2)\pi$, where $\tan x$ is negative and large enough to counter $x^2$.